# Format vba msgbox to show cells with two decimal houses

Tags: excel, vba

The cells which the code is pointing (b2, b3 ..) are already showing up 2 decimal houses, but the msg box shows many . How can I fix it? I had an attempt with & _
    Format(dTotalArea, "0.00"), but didnt work.

Many thanks in advance.

```
MsgBox "First Response Time (hours)= " & _
Worksheets("Results").Range("B2").Value & _
vbCrLf & "Investigation Time (hours)= " & _
Worksheets("Results").Range("B3").Value & _
vbCrLf & "Nr of Incidents Resolved= " & _
Worksheets("Results").Range("B4").Value & _
vbCrLf & "Resolved Same Day (%)= " & _
Worksheets("Results").Range("B5").Value & _
Format(dTotalArea, "0.00"), , "title_of_msgbox"
```

Comment: What variable type is dTotalArea?

Comment: @99moorem I added that command because found it on web. But it doesnt work... :/ Can be removed.

Comment: What is dTotalArea declared as? Is this your full code? (if not could you post please) What is in dTotalArea when the code gets to the format line?

Comment: @99moorem ignore that part of code. I copied from web.. as attempt to change format

Comment: @99moorem Can I specify that dTotalArea  are cells B3,B4,B5 in the sheet results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
MsgBox "First Response Time (hours)= " & _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value & _
vbCrLf & "Investigation Time (hours)= " & _
Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value, "0.00") & _
vbCrLf & "Nr of Incidents Resolved= " & _
Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value, "0.00") & _
vbCrLf & "Resolved Same Day (%)= " & _
Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value, "0.00") _
, , "title_of_msgbox"
```